# Notifying that value has changed

Tags: java, android

I'm writing radio player on android. I want to use RDS fucntion and display text in GUI. I have object that manage radio and its functions. When something changes, like RDS text, i want publish it in simple TextBox inside Activity. How i can notify GUI that one of property has changed (and send new value) and i have to refresh that property? Is there any mechanism inside Android that provide such asynchronous notification functionality? I've read about
`PropertyChangeListener` but this is mechanizm for JavaBeans, can I adopt that? If yes, tell me how i can register and use change listeners in my case.

Comment: use java interfaces, declare your interface in the RDS class and implement it on the GUI class.

Comment: OK, interfaces. But then i have to run some Thread in background that will be ask RDS class if something changed. I don't think that is good idea. I know that i can do something like change listeners but i don't know how.

Comment: can you post your RDS class?

Comment: Unfortunately no, this is part of bigger buisness project, I can't publish it. We can simplify question to:"how notify across android application that some important value has changed and it have to be published?"

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_Data_System <- RDS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Observer Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

Comment: In this case i can unregister my reciever in onPause() method to avoid null pointer exceptions?

Comment: Yes you can, or you can check if activity.isFinishing() and if not refresh your screen in callback

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) for this job. Here is some examples:

- https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html
- http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/A_Basic_Overview_of_Android_Threads_and_Thread_handlers

Cheers

Comment: OK, i got that. I have to pass handler object to the buisness class? If I change activity to, lets say "settings", I got null pointer exception if something occurs?

Comment: "Settings" is an Activity, just PreferenceActivity (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Activity).

Comment: I added this as a example, is na Activity, no preference activity.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class like this:

```
abstract class RDSTextListener {
    public abstract void onRDSTextChanged(String newText);
}
```

From your activity do something like:

```
RDSTextListener listener = new RDSTextListener() {

    public void onRDSTextChanged(String newText) {

         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
         @Override
         public void run() {

         ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.your_text_view)).setText(newText);

         }});
    }

}
```

You will have to pass this listener to your business class. The business class will then call onRDSTextChanged() when its appropriate, and the UI will be updated.

**EDIT:** Note, this doesn't use interfaces. An abstract class instead. I think that's more Android friendly, avoiding needlessly processing power.